# what is wrong with deploy heroku strapi app

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, strapi

I am trying to deploy strapi app with mongoose connector but getting this error.

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './DropdownIndicator' in '/tmp/build_754325e2_/.cache/admin/src/components/Roles/ConditionsSelect'
at /tmp/build_754325e2_/node_modules/strapi-admin/index.js:70:23
at finalCallback (/tmp/build_754325e2_/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
at onCompiled (/tmp/build_754325e2_/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:265:20)
at /tmp/build_754325e2_/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:670:21
at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_754325e2_/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :28:1)

can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting your cache folder then `npm run build` then push to heroku.